# alpinejs refs not available in event

Tags: alpine.js

I'm new to alpine and trying to leverage it to the best of my abilities. In particular, I want to use `x-ref` for an input so I don't have to use a query selector, but although it works fine in my `x-data` block (in `getErrorMessage`), at the level of the submit event in the form, `this.$refs.email` is always undefined.

```
 <form
   @submit.prevent="() => {
     errorMessage = getErrorMessage();
     const invalid = !!errorMessage;
     if (!invalid)
       submit(this.$refs.email.value);
   }"
   x-data="{
     errorMessage: '', 
     blur() {
       this.errorMessage = this.getErrorMessage();
     },
     getErrorMessage() {
       const result = Iodine.assert(this.$refs.email.value, ['required', 'email']);
       if(!result.valid) {
         return result.error;
       }
       return '';
     }
   }"
 >
   <input
     type="text"
     placeholder="Enter email address"
     type="email"
     x-ref="email"
     id="email"
   />
   <p
     x-show="errorMessage"
     x-text="errorMessage"
   ></p>
 </form>
```

Am I misunderstanding how regs and events work in Alpine?

I thought `this.$refs.email` would be available in the form `@submit` event, but it is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In directives, refs are accessed via `$refs`, not `this.$refs`:

```js
window.Iodine = {
  assert: () => true,
};

window.submit = (...args) => console.log(...args);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>

<form
  @submit.prevent="() => {
    errorMessage = getErrorMessage();
    const invalid = !!errorMessage;
    if (!invalid)
     submit($refs.email.value);
  }"
  x-data="{
    errorMessage: '', 
    blur() {
      this.errorMessage = this.getErrorMessage();
    },
    getErrorMessage() {
      const result = Iodine.assert(this.$refs.email.value, ['required', 'email']);
      if(!result.valid) {
        return result.error;
      }
      return '';
    }
  }"
>
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter email address"
  type="email"
  x-ref="email"
  id="email"
/>
<p
  x-show="errorMessage"
  x-text="errorMessage"
></p>
</form>
```

This can be seen in [the documentation example](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/refs):

```html
<button @click="$refs.text.remove()">Remove Text</button>
 
<span x-ref="text">Hello </span>
```